# Adding features in game dev tycoon

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

In Game Dev Tycoon, when you go to add features into your game, it will give you the little percentage next to the sliders which means you've added too many to do them all efficiently, but does this effect anything in any way? Are your review scores hurt by this? Are your sales of this game hurt by this? Does this matter at all, or should I just throw every single feature in to make an amazing game?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The percentage is only shown if the features exceed the time planned for this part of the game.
To get a good rating you have to focus on the right things. If you focus on everything, you are not focussing at all.. Including features (such as Advanced Cutscenes or Accurate Weather) affect the overall rating of the game positively if the area (e.g. World Design) is important for that type of game.

As you cannot "pause" any stage of the game, you will not be able to include everything by just exceeding deadlines - the next stage of development will start automatically. So if you have any area below 100% (so anything that is shown), this will have a negative effect for the rating.